# Making components invisible with button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

How can I make a component on my MainUI invisible by pressing a button? I want to dismiss a warning box on my MainActivity with a button that says "Close" or with a cross image.

Comment: What is the component that you want invisible?

Comment: @EmilyHommerding I want to make 3 buttons that are inside a RelativeLayout invisible by pressing a button with a cross image (already designed the UI).

Comment: Add a ID to your relative layout, then initialize it in code as any other view component. Then use relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); or View.INVISIBLE

Comment: @Linxy Avoid answering the question in comments. Post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button crossButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.crossImage)
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne)
//and so on

crossButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        button1.setVisibility(GONE);
        //and so on
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Emily, I'm still trying because the previous answer didn't described well.

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

where view is the component you want to hide

Comment: Thanks Will for the response I will now try to do it.